# Adaptive padding vs. custom padding SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was reading through this [post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tips-and-tricks) and came across the section titled "Rely On Adaptive Padding."

It sounds like if you use `padding()` without customizing it, then the framework will automatically handle auto layouts for different devices and device orientation like landscape and portrait. Does that mean if you customize the modifier like this as an example, `padding(10)`, then there's a possibility the auto layout from the framework won't work as expected for different devices because of the custom value?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `padding()` without a value, you get the adaptive padding. As described in the document you linked to:

> So, if your app is running on an iPad with a regular size class you’ll get more padding than if the user moves it down to a split view – all without having to write any code.

If you use a value, such as your example `padding(10)`, you will get `10` pts of padding, no matter what the device. That doesn't mean that "auto layout from the framework won't work as expected" as you put it -- it just means that you'll get a padding of `10` regardless of device.

It comes down to intension -- there may be times when you want device/size-specific padding and there may be times when you want an exact amount regardless of the environment it is in.

More useful reading in the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/padding(_:_:)